# How to group timestamps every 1day in group of 3objects max per array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, datetime

[Junior Dev !!]
[Javascript]
Hi !

##### How do i group timestamps every 1day + each group has a MAX capicity of 3 object??

i saw in other question where people are grouping only by timestamp but how do we order and we give a max capacity to an array at the same time?

#### I have:

```
const restuls= [
{date: "2022-10-14T21:14:41.000Z", id: "1"},
{date: "2022-10-14T21:15:48.000Z", id: "2"},
{date: "2022-09-20T18:16:01.000Z", id: "3"},
{date: "2022-09-20T18:16:48.000Z", id: "4"},
{date: "2022-09-20T21:14:52.000Z", id: "5"},
{date: "2022-09-20T21:14:15.000Z", id: "6"},
{date: "2022-09-20T21:14:03.000Z", id: "7"},
{date: "2022-09-18T10:09:33.000Z", id: "8"},
{date: "2022-09-18T10:08:12.000Z", id: "9"},
{date: "2022-09-18T10:07:50.000Z", id: "10"}
]
```

#### Expected output:

```
[
  [
   {date: "2022-10-14T21:14:41.000Z", id: "1"},
   {date: "2022-10-14T21:15:48.000Z", id: "2"}
  ],

  [
   {date: "2022-09-20T18:16:01.000Z", id: "3"},
   {date: "2022-09-20T18:16:48.000Z", id: "4"},
   {date: "2022-09-20T21:14:52.000Z", id: "5"}
  ],
  [
   {date: "2022-09-20T21:14:15.000Z", id: "6"},
   {date: "2022-09-20T21:14:03.000Z", id: "7"}
  ],
  [
   {date: "2022-09-18T10:09:33.000Z", id: "8"},
   {date: "2022-09-18T10:08:12.000Z", id: "9"},
   {date: "2022-09-18T10:07:50.000Z", id: "10"}
  ],
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+group+object+array+timestamp+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Reduce comes to mind

Comment: Hi, @mplungjan what don't you understand in my question? .. I add a minimal example of what i have and my expected output.

Comment: You do not have any attempt. It is not an example of what you tried. Of course I understand what you need. We are not e-lancing :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple function would do the trick using a modulo.

Quickly typed this code while at work, this may need a bit of re-factorization.

EDITED:

```js
results = [{
    date: "2022-10-14T21:14:41.000Z",
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    date: "2022-10-14T21:15:48.000Z",
    id: "2"
  },
  {
    date: "2022-09-20T18:16:01.000Z",
    id: "3"
  },
  {
    date: "2022-09-20T18:16:48.000Z",
    id: "4"
  },
  {
    date: "2022-09-20T21:14:52.000Z",
    id: "5"
  },
  {
    date: "2022-09-20T21:14:15.000Z",
    id: "6"
  },
  {
    date: "2022-09-20T21:14:03.000Z",
    id: "7"
  },
  {
    date: "2022-09-18T10:09:33.000Z",
    id: "8"
  },
  {
    date: "2022-09-18T10:08:12.000Z",
    id: "9"
  },
  {
    date: "2022-09-18T10:07:50.000Z",
    id: "10"
  }
];

function groupByDateMaxThreeItems(array) {
  index = 0;
  arr = [];
  result = [];
  array = array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
  });

  for (item of array) {
    index = index + 1;
    if (index % 3 === 0 || !isSameDay(array[index - 1], item)) {
      result.push(arr);
      arr = [];
    }
    arr.push(item)
  }
  return result;
}

function isSameDay(item1, item2) {
  date1 = new Date(item1.date);
  date2 = new Date(item2.date);

  return (
    date1.getYear() + date1.getMonth() + date1.getDay() ==
    date2.getYear() + date2.getMonth() + date2.getDay()
  );
}

console.log(groupByDateMaxThreeItems(results));
```

Comment: This does not work. You forgot to group on date

Comment: Ah very true, my bad this is only half an answer

Comment: i was checking it and yes these is just grouping but not checking the dates.. still thanks

Comment: I'm gonna edit my answer with somthing that should work. Not sure this is the most optimized tho you would have to look into that

Comment: Wow thanks for comming back <3

Comment: Hi i think isSameDay is not working because i end up with groups of mixed dates in the moment when i start to put several inputs